# Permission to unshared document on Google Drive (Google Drive Security)

Tags: google-drive, security, google-drive-sharing

We've just had a very strange situation happen. A family member just sent my wife (an automated) email from Google asking permission to share a document we don't want to share with anyone else.

We know for sure that we have not shared this document with anyone (only my wife and I have access to it) and it is not shared publicly (with an encrypted link).

What we're trying to work out is how she managed to get access to this file in the first place. We only have her as an email contact in Gmail of course but never have shared any Google docs with her in the past.

This has gotten us worried and want to know if anyone else has/is experiencing this?

Comment: Is it possible that the link to the document got leaked to your relative somehow? A long email chain, perhaps? Decline the permission, obviously, but you might want to ask where the link came from.

Comment: I concur with Al: they must have had access to that link to the document (e-mail chain, browser history, etc.). Since Google Drive provides no logs of who tried to access documents, you don't have many options other than asking the family member in question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking and disabling any and all sharing for the Sheet in Google Drive. That should stop anyone who has the link from using it or sharing it (accidentally or purposefully) and further